# Make textboxes and textareas longer

Tags: html, css, textbox

I have a table with Textboxes and one Textarea. I would like to increase the length of these items horizontally, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I've tried using width on the `textboxes` and cols on the `textarea` but nothing has worked yet.

Here is a link to my jsfiddlefor this page that I am working on:
[JS FiddleLink](https://jsfiddle.net/1zfmzn96/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your css:

```
input, textarea { width: 100%; }
```

That should make it so that the input and textarea takes up 100% of the container's width.

Afterwards, you can then change the container's width with css. For example, your table `.Contact-Table` is currently set as 200px so the input and textarea is 200px. Setting your `.Contact-Table` to 300px will also affect the input and textareas because they are set as 100% width.

Answer (score 0):

width attribute is not allowed for input and Textarea; use CSS styling instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are using width attribute on your textbox and text area. Replace that width attribute with style="width:100px;" or whatever number of pixels you want to use. 
For example,

```
<input type="text" name="email" style="width:100px;">
```

Alternatively, you can use css selectors do achieve the same.

```
<style>
input, textarea {
    width:100px; //change this to any other value
}
</style>
```